# Internet Explorer 11 HTML5 audio duration = infinity issue

Tags: html, audio, ffmpeg, converters, internet-explorer-11

Today I've met an unpleasant issue. There is a website with a custom HTML5 audio player. After the page loads, I try to echo `document.getElementById("myAudioId").duration`, it is needed in order to make navigation possible. In every other browser it works just fine, the duration is showed, but IE11 works differently - it shows that duration equals `Infinity`. But as I noticed, when the song is buffered to the end, the duration magically appers and the navigation works. In other browsers everything works from the start. The content-length headers are set up. What could it be?

**UPD:** Other sites with HTML5 audio let me see the duration from the very start. The duration, I guess, is part of metadata and could be loaded even without preloading the audio file using `preload="metadata"`, but it also doesn't work.

**UPD2:** I've also tried playing around with **jsfiddle** and created the same audio tag there with same MP3 audio - there was the same situation. But then I've inserted link to another MP3 there, from another site - *and it worked!*. More than that, I've uploaded this second song to the first problematic website and after that the song that worked perfectly couldn't also show me its duration and stuff. So now I think it's something on server side. But don't know what it is.

**UPD3:** Finally, I've been told that files are converted using **FFMPEG** to MP3 128bit, then they stop being OK. Now I need to find how should I convert MP3s so they are OK.

Comment: From to the documentation: **duration** _Read only_ (double) The length of the media in seconds, or zero if no media data is available.  If the media data is available but the length is unknown, this value is NaN.  **If the media is streamed and has no predefined length, the value is Inf**. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement - Conclusion: IE only assumes the length when it is fully buffered.

Comment: @somethinghere and what about [this demo](http://demos.w3avenue.com/html5-unleashed-tips-tricks-and-techniques/sample-04-audio-demo.html)? IE can recognize the duration from the very start. Maybe the `controls` attribute is the one that matters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works for me locally, but when uploaded to server, it does not.
It seems that player.duration do not work in IE 11: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn254962(v=vs.85).aspx